# meaning of stat symbolic names

Tags: c, macros, stat

In the stat.h there are many symbolic names... (for an example : S_IRWXU). I can able to understand the meaning of R,W,X. But **I cannot able to understand the meaning of S_I**. Though it is not essential to know the meaning behind this, I am eager to know about this.
**Someone explain please....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the prefix has any real meaning. The "S_" part is appropriate for `stat`, like the "O_" defines for `open`. Some other people have wondered, e.g. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/sys-stat-h-what-does-the-letter-i-mean-840115/

Comment: Thank you Sir for Providing that great Link.Now You have increased my eagerness to Know about that sir. Is really the I means Illegible? Please Help again..

Comment: No, that was a joke. There doesn't appear to be an authoritative source for why the `I` is there.